# Method to println to txt file

Tags: java, logging

I have a Java program littered with values I want to log to a txt file. I'm new to the language and finding it not so straight forward.

I created a `Logger` class:

```
public static void loggerMain(String content) {    
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("debug.txt", true)));
        out.println(content);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
    }
}
```

I then call the method in another class:

```
Logger.loggerMain("testing");
```

It logs the String but if I then run the script again, it will append the same String to a new line.But I don't want the same `println` to be appended each time the script is called. I want to override the file. How would I go about this?

If I change the `FileWriter` argument to `False`, the file will only log the latest call to the method. e.g.:

```
Logger.loggerMain("testing1");
Logger.loggerMain("testing2");
```

Only `Logger.loggerMain("testing2");` will be logged. I know why, it's because I'm creating a new file each time I call the method.. but I really don't know the solution to this!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "I don't want the same `println` to be appended each time the script is called. *I want to override the file.*"? Based on last sentence it looks like you want to get rid of old content of file and replace it with new content. But in that case changing `true` to `false` is what you would want, but later you said you tried that and it still doesn't do what you want. Can you explain what you expect to happen when you call `Logger.loggerMain("foo"); Logger.loggerMain("Bar")`? How resulting file should look like?

Comment: The resulting file will just contain 'Bar', as this was the last call to LoggerMain

Comment: I am not asking what it *will* contain, I am asking what you *want/expect* it to contain. Should it contain only "Bar"? If yes, then what is the problem with changing `true` to `false` (which should achieve exactly that)?

Comment: I want it to contain 'foo', 'bar'.

Comment: @arsenal88 have a look at my question. I assume this might solve your problem. if not then please clarify your question further

Comment: Can you be more precise about expected content? Should I take it literally and assume you want to add quotes and commas like `'foo','bar'`? Or maybe should it be one line without quote or commas like `'foobar'` or maybe just commas `foo,bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to clear the log for every time the programm is executed. You can do this with the following addition to the `Logger` class:

```
class Logger {
    private static boolean FIRST_CALL = true;

    public static void loggerMain(String content) {    
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("debug.txt", !FIRST_CALL)));

            if(FIRST_CALL){
                FIRST_CALL = false;
            }
            out.println(content);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
    }
}
```

With the variable `FIRST_CALL` we track if the logger has been executed for the first time in the current script context. If it is, we overwrite the file, by passing in `false` (`!FIRST_CALL`) into the `FileWriter`

Comment: I tried this implementation and when calling the method twice, it still only takes the latest method's print statement. I want both method calls to be in the txt output. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a re-iteration of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023273/7916438):

```
class Logger {
    private static boolean FIRST_CALL = true;

    public static void loggerMain(String content) {    
        try (
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("debug.txt", !FIRST_CALL)))) {
            FIRST_CALL = false;
            out.println(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
    }
}
```

1. [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) will spare you an explicit `close()` call, and will properly close the resource regardless of completing the block normally or with an exception.
2. This one is subjective: as the code will touch `FIRST_CALL` anyway, I feel it simpler to set it without the extra check.

Comment: Thought about those points too. The last one bothers me a bit. As I don't like overwriting a variable always. But I am not sure what is more time consuming, checking it or overwriting it. Anyway, good answer! :)

Comment: @Lino Yes, on the CPU level you are absolutely right (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417481/what-specifically-marks-an-x86-cache-line-as-dirty-any-write-or-is-an-explici), just here files are involved, so a dirty cache-line matters very little.